# Pass array to a function instead of variable

Tags: c

I have a pretty basic problem, but I really don't understand what's going on.

I just want to create a function which takes an array as input instead of a double. Why are the following two code segments not the same, not even for j == 0? (I get different values when printing ***buf**)

1.)

```
void
SVPublisher_ASDU_setFLOAT64(SVPublisher_ASDU self, int index, double value)
{
    uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*) &value;
```

print:

```
valueArray value: 1.145000
```

2.)

```
void
SVPublisher_ASDU_setFLOAT64Array(SVPublisher_ASDU self, int index, const double* valueArray, int length)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
        uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*) (valueArray + 8 * j);
```

print:

```
valueArray value: 3070733822295138354700875252470016317131267959765042782153548795915832793917922493698408448.000000
```

uint8_t is unsigned char

Comment: in rhe 2nd snippet you want `(uint8_t*)&valueArray[j]`

Comment: In the first function, you are casting the pointer value from double to uint8_t and you get the address in buf lets say e.g: 0xFF. in the second function you are casting the valueArray to uint8_t (also fine nothing wrong), but you get and you should and you wull get deffrent addresses at each time you run the code! Do you understand that ?!
at each run the linker will allocate diffrent addresses.

Comment: Your actual issue is hard to identify to me. When asking a question take care of that it shall be as focused as possible. If you got several issues you struggling with, ask different focused questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*) &value;` sets `buf` to the address of `value`, which is a parameter, meaning it is a copy of the argument that was passed. The compiler has put that copy somewhere, so `buf` gets the address of that location. `uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*) (valueArray + 8 * j);` sets `buf` to an address calculated from `valueArray`, which is an address passed to it, and that address is the start of some array (or single object) of the caller. There is no reason to expect these to be the same; the address of a parameter in one set of source code is largely unrelated to the address of some array in another set of source code.

Additionally, `(uint8_t*) (valueArray + 8 * j);` is not likely the calculation you want. Since `valueArray` is a pointer to `double`, the address arithmetic with `+ 8 * j` works in units of `double`, so `valueArray + 8 * j` is a place in memory that is displaced from `valueArray` by the size of `8 * j` objects of type `double`. The later cast to `(uint8_t *)` does not affect this; it causes a conversion after the arithmetic. You might want `(uint8_t *) (valueArray + j)` here, but it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the blurry question, I had a typo, I meant *buf instead of buf.
_"Since valueArray is a pointer to double, the address arithmetic with + 8 * j works in units of double..."_ 

I didn't know this, that was the problem.